# Subtracting times across a day in excel

Tags: excel

I am working on the capstone project in of the Google Career Certificate in Data Analytics. I am using Microsoft Excel. I have to calculate the ride length based on the start and end ride times. I've inputted the formula =F2(end time)-D2(start time) which returns the ride length. Going through my entire list I have some areas where the start time is like 11pm and the end time is 1am and this is returning ###### because it is a negative number with the regular formula. I've found a modified formula that can kind of do the conversion I am looking for but it is still a bit problematic. The modified formula is =(F2-D2+(F2<D2))*24 and it seems to give an accurate ride length if I reformat the answer to number. The issue is the rest of my data is in time format and the modified ones are in number format. If I convert the number values to time, the ride length values are inaccurate.

It is tricky to make the numeric value change as well due to me using a formula. I can correct them one by one after I save Excel and it no longer stores the numbers as the formula, but there are lots of data points to change and that would be time consuming. I'm hoping to find a more concise way to solve this problem. Maybe with a better formula.

[Snippet of the chart [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7V4V.png)

Comment: Don't multiply by 24!

Answer (score 0):

Just like everything in life, there are multiple ways to achieve things. I would have formatted the date and time into a single cell; but. if you're gathering the data from another source, that's understandable.

A simple IF statement here will work. IF the days are one apart, then take '1' day off the starting time, else do your original formula:

```
=IF(E4-C4=1,F4-(D4-1),F4-D4)
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I will give that a shot and see if I get better results

Comment: Having the formula in the datetime format side stepped the need for a separate negative formula altogether. Funny thing is that was how the data set was initially but then I separated them in my cleaning process. In other words, I created my own problem lol, but I guess you live and learn in this business. Thanks again!

Comment: Would you mind marking the answer accepted if it's helped solve your problem

Comment: Sure thing, how would I do that?